# Qt Creator The plugin platforms/qminimal.dll uses incompatible Qt library

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qt-creator, windbg

Windows 10 pro x64,
Qt 5.15.5 msvc 2019, clang, Qt Creator 9.0.2:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

my code crashes at the line:

```
Q_ASSERT(!pluginName.isEmpty());
auto loaderPtr = std::make_unique<QPluginLoader>(pluginName);
const bool firstLoad = !loaderPtr->isLoaded();
auto& loader = *loaderPtr;
if(!loader.load()) /// <= crashes here, no messages shown
    qCritical() << tr("cannot load the plugin %1: %2").arg(pluginName, loader.errorString());
```

Also there are suspicious messages in the Application Output before the crash:

```
"The plugin 'C:/Qt/5.15.5/msvc/plugins/platforms/qminimal.dll' uses incompatible Qt library. (Cannot mix debug and release libraries.)" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "C:/Qt/5.15.5/msvc/plugins/platforms/qminimald.dll"
```

**How to fix that?**

Comment: You tagged this WinDbg but I see no debugging approach. What were your steps in WinDbg to debug this? What about the `firstLoad` variable? It seems unused. Should you use it? Why do you use `*loaderPtr` which may result in undefined behavior instead of `loaderPtr->get()` which returns a `nullptr` which you could check against? And why don't you operate on the `unique_ptr` directly, which would be the idea of a smart pointer? Can't you simply write `loaderPtr->load()`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'm sure the code is correct, the problem is somehow related to the incompatibility of binary libraries